# How to install java 7 in chef cookbook using json override

Tags: java, chef-infra

I have a web server role in my chef recipe like so

```
name "webserver"

'nginx' => {
   'port' => "80"
},
'java' => {
   'openjdk_version' => 7
}
```

Berksfile

```
cookbook "java"
```

I am trying to install java 7 - cannot seem to find a example of doing this inside a json override.

Current error is ERROR: Option version must be a kind of [String, Array]!  You passed 8.

Thanks

Comment: Which cookbooks do you use?

Comment: @Roland updated my question - is it possible to do this through Berkshelf and not an override?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to override anything if you're using a role, just set the `openjdk_version` attribute as part of the default_attributes section of the role. That attribute is set to `nil` in the cookbook's `attributes/default.rb` so you only need to set it by following Chef's normal [order of precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence).

Example (JSON):

```
{
  "name": "webserver",
  "default_attributes": {
    "nginx": {
        "port": "80"
    },
    "java": {
      "openjdk_version": "7"
    }
  }
}
```

Same thing using the Ruby DSL:

```
name "webserver"
default_attributes => {
  "nginx" => {
    "port" => "80"
  },
  "java" => {
    "openjdk_version" => "7"
  }
}
```

If you're using a wrapper cookbook of some kind, you could also set the attribute via that cookbook's attributes file(s), e.g.:
`default[:java][:openjdk_version] = "7"`

This `ERROR: Option version must be a kind of [String, Array]! You passed 8.` error you're getting is because you're setting the attribute as an integer, not a string. If you look at the [cookbook's code](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java/blob/c9abfc8168e38ef5fc21d5b811bf6184d937827a/recipes/openjdk.rb#L45-L49), you can see where the `version` option is called. I've honestly never used that option but it sounds like it wants a string, and the examples support that notion (see the Chef docs for the package resource -- I can't post the link because I already have too many links in this post).

As for using Berkshelf, keep in mind Berkshelf is for resolving dependencies and making your life easier when it comes to managing said dependencies and uploading them to your node or your Chef server. It's not used for setting Chef attributes.

I hope this helps!